# Office 365 developer subscription and PowerApps

Tags: office365, powerapps

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/developer-program/office-365-developer-program-faq) page at Microsoft indicates that PowerApps is included in an Office 365 developer subscription.  But in mine, I have SharePoint, but I don't see PowerApps.  I don't even see the Office apps.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I didn't realize that you have to assign licenses to users even within a developer subscription!  But that's exactly what's required.

- Log into your Office 365 developer account
- There you'll see your Office 365 developer subscription.  Click "Go to subscription"
- In the Apps menu go to the Admin app
- Under Users, go to Active Users
- Find your user, and assign the Office 365 E3 Developer license

Now that the license is assigned, all of the apps will be available in your dev subscription.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted, so that if others have the same issue as you did, they will find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go to `https://yourDomain.sharepoint.com` and click the "waffle menu" in the top left to see all available apps. PowerApps should be listed there.

[image: waffle menu]

Another option is to go to `https://make.powerapps.com` and login with your Microsoft credentials.

Comment: Sorry, none of that worked.  It just isn't there in the list, hence posting my question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you login to https://portal.office.com and login within your credentials . Click All apps

[image]

You should be able to see powerapps.

Alternatively the easiest way is: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/ and sign up / sign in

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry that app is just not there.  And there's no login that I have that gives it to me at that URL.